# What to do if Windows keeps getting corrupted?

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd, file-corruption

For the second time now, my PC has just randomly not been able to boot and got stuck in an automatic repair loop. The error code I get when trying to boot is `0xc000021a`. I've tried everything and it seems the only solution is to reinstall Windows in order to be able to turn on my computer again.

This is incredibly frustrating because I lose all my programs and files each time.

What is the issue? Could it be my SSD? I bought it only a couple of years ago!

I have no idea what could be going wrong? I couldn't find much online on this problem.

Edit: After doing some more research online, could it be that my SSD is failing? (but it is only 1-2 years old?!!)

Comment: Any issues with power in your building or in your area? Reason I ask is because I have clients in Mexico who have to put their PCs on a UPS due to frequent outages to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Moses No, I live in Canada and the quality of power is quite good here.

Comment: Have you used any hardware diagnostics? I would run it on the SSD and RAM for starters.

Comment: @Moses How would I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything.  I have ran the same installation of Windows across multiple computers for over a decade.  The worst case is I had to restore from a month old backup because of a bad HDD.

Comment: Manufacturers usually have their own diagnostic tools you can access in the BIOS. If yours is custom built or doesn't have that option, you can use Seagate's tools to check the SSD: http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/

Comment: and memtest for the memory: http://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: I tried `sfc -scannow` and it gave me the error "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation after the verification phase".

Comment: Do a test on your RAM. Use memtest86 or similar

Comment: @Mokubai Would that fix the problem? Or just tell me that there is a problem?

Comment: memtest86 just tells you if your RAM is good, if it find errors you will have to buy new RAM.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a little bit on the internet I found this page,

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/windows-8-pro-cannot-boot-error-0xc000021a/ebf26ca7-e594-4c56-bbe0-cca43dfe5978

Where a guy says

> i had this problem and i fixed it. i faced this after updating my win8 and rebooting after that update.
>   i tried safe mode but it failed to boot. finally i tried to boot with "force drivers to have signature disabled" and it worked.

Don't know if this will help you but its worth a try! It's marked as best answer over there so it helped some people!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up isolating the problem to a faulty SSD and it is now being sent for repairs. I will leave this answer here in case others run into the same problem.